# Limit Access to all files from within a specified directory on LAMP Server

Tags: apache, directory, chmod

I have a folder on my site (media) that I do not want the public to access, even if they know the full file names.

I believe this is done with chmod controls but not sure. How can I limit access so that only my Server is able to access all of the contents within the directory (css, js, mainly PDF files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your httpd.conf or an included .conf file add:

```
<Directory /dir/to/be/protected>
    AllowOverride None
    <Limit GET POST OPTIONS>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </Limit>
</Directory>
```

Comment: excellent - just what I was looking for. If you don't mind, so I can learn, what does the Limit section do?

Comment: It's a filter, you can filter out whatever you do or don't want to happen.  There is also LimitExcept directive which is more used to make sure only X or Y happen in this context.  More documentation at: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#limit

Answer (score 1):

Just add this into your .htaccess

```
Deny from all
Allow from IP
```

More info here
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_access.html

Also if you want to deny all access by http (for example you access this files with php script), then just add Deny without Allow.

UPD: In your VirtualHost you can do something like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName domain
DocumentRoot /var/www/domain/
<Directory "/var/www/domain/deny_folder/">
Deny from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I do this already for certain site but I want to limit to specific directories which is not allowed in HTACCESS. I believe I can set this within a vhost.conf file on my machine set to <Directory></Directory> Limits on my actual IP but I am curious if there is a better way.

Comment: I should have really tested on my own first but ultimately was looking for the LIMIT functions awm explains.